# Gmail message sent issue

Tags: gmail, account-management

I sent someone a picture of my mothers social security card by accident they have not seen it through gmail into their personal work email.. and I don’t want her to see it if I report her as spam will she still be able to read my email and see the attachment? I am scared

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. I'm sorry, but it's unclear what is your question about.